# Recursive Function Call Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm writing an element that recursively builds a menu tree from a JSON object. However, when the function calls itself I get the error: `this.buildMenu is not a function`

Here's buildMenu

```
buildMenu: function(items) {
var node = new Array();

items.forEach(function(elem,index,arr) {
    node.push(elem.Name);

    if (elem.SubBranch.length > 0) {
        return this.buildMenu(elem.SubBranch); //error is here
    }
});

return node;
}
```

The original method that calls buildMenu

```
handleRes: function() {
    this.response = this.$.categoryList.lastResponse;
    this.menuItems = this.buildMenu(this.response);
    //...
}
```

I've verified that data is there and formatted correctly. If I comment out the recursive call, I get the first layer of results. So, it's working in that respect.

The `elem.SubBranch` argument that is called in the recursive call is an array, and completely valid, if that matters.

Comment: Can you build a plunker to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that inside the forEach callback function, *this* refers to the context of the callback function itself. Then, when this.buildMenu is called, it fails because the function is not defined within that context.

The forEach function accepts an argument to provide the object you want to be used when the *this* keyword is used. In this case you may use the following code:

```
buildMenu: function(items) {
var node = new Array();

items.forEach(function(elem,index,arr) {
    node.push(elem.Name);

    if (elem.SubBranch.length > 0) {
        return this.buildMenu(elem.SubBranch); //error is here
    }
}, this);

return node;
}
```

Note the *this* parameter provided after the callback.